# How to Prevent Overflow in Odoo 15

Tags: xml, odoo-15

Good day,
How can I prevent this overflow in tree tag
[image]

Below is my page line code

```
<notebook>
    <page name="inc_produt_line" string="Insurance Lines">
        <group>
            <field name="inc_line_ids" nolabel="1">
                <tree string="Insurance" editable="bottom">
                    <field name="product_id"/>
                    <field name="name" required="1"/>
            </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Comment: Please show your form definition.

Comment: @Paxmees i have edited the question to add my notebook code

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module, add this to the style (css) file.

Add this:

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

To test it first you can right click your form and click "Inspect", then look for the div with class="table-responsive".   The table should now fit into the parent div with a scroll bar underneath.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but my default it is their

Comment: Can you elaborate or share your custom style code?  You might have another module that is overriding the normal code.